# ES6 javascript tests using Tape and Nightmare.js

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, nightmare, node.js-tape

I've been trying to test my ES6 code using [Tape](https://github.com/substack/tape) assertions and [Nightmare.js](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare) to load a test page. I keep trying different ES6 methods: async/await, yield, generators, and I think I'm a bit over my head. I'm also not sure when and when to not use [babel-tape](https://github.com/spion/blue-tape). I can get the following test to pass, but the minute I create another evaluate block it errors out. The documentation is fairly scarce (or uses Mocha). What's the best practice here?

```js
import {test} from "tape";
import {default as nightmare} from "nightmare";

const page = nightmare().goto("http://localhost:4000/index.html");

page.evaluate(() => document.getElementsByTagName("body").length).end()
  .then((result) => {
    test("detect page body", (assert) => {
      assert.equal(1, result);
      assert.end();
    });
  });
```

ps. I'm using [babel-tape-runner](https://github.com/wavded/babel-tape-runner) to run the tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can get the following test to pass, but the minute I create another evaluate block it errors out.

Hm, you're calling `.end()` on the Nightmare instance.  You shouldn't be interacting with that instance once it ends, that is probably causing you some of your problems.

> The documentation is fairly scarce (or uses Mocha)

If you take a look at the test suite in Nightmare, the `describe` blocks have a `beforeEach` and `afterEach` that sets up or destroys the Nightmare instance, respectively.  Your test - at least in my read - would set up a single Nightmare instance for all of your tests, which may lead to undesirable behavior.

---

All that said, you might want to try moving the declaration and usage of Nightmare internal to your tests.  Off the cuff, something like:

```
import {test} from "tape";
import {default as Nightmare} from "nightmare";

test('detect page body', (assert) => {
 var nightmare = Nightmare();
 nightmare
    .goto("http://localhost:4000/index.html")
    .evaluate(() => document.getElementsByTagName("body").length)
    .then((result) => {
      assert.equal(1, result);
      nightmare.end(()=>{
        assert.end();
      });
    });
});
```